# Concatenating two arrays into single array using python

Tags: python, arrays

hopefully it is very simple question...but not for me...
I have two arrays:

```
A = [12,23,12,9]  
B = [3,2,7,4]
```

I want the output in this form using python:

```
C=[[12,3],[23,2],[12,7],[9,4]]
```

Comment: what have you tried? SO isn't here to teach you a language, there are tutorial sites for that.

Comment: `Itertools` is your friend here

Comment: `Itertools` already mentioned - if you really want a list of lists: `[[A[i],B[i]] for i in range(len(A))]`; if a list of tuples is acceptable, `zip(A,B)`... There are plenty of other ways to do it...

Comment: Thank you guys for your advice...
[[A[i],B[i]] for i in range(len(A))] really works

Answer (score 5):

You could use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function:

```
>>> A = [12,23,12,9]
>>> B = [3,2,7,4]

>>> print zip(A, B)
```

However, zip it returns a tuple but you can change to a list. So it would work as well:

```
>>> C = [list(g) for g in zip(A, B)] #returns [[12, 3], [23, 2], [12, 7], [9, 4]]
```